# Return list of companies depending on search term

Tags: json, angular

I am creating a mock api which involves querying a json file (containing company objects) for a particular name, but it keeps on returning null instead of the matches. How can I fix this? I based the work off this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/).

Code

```
  filterCompanies(searchTerm) {
    this.http.get('assets/data/companies.json').map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
      this.companies = data;
      return this.companies.filter((company) => {
        return company.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    });
  }
```

companies.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "one"
  },
  {
    "name": "two"
  },
  {
    "name": "three"
  },
  {
    "name": "four"
  },
  {
    "name": "five"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using return, you can directly assign the values,

```
 this.companies = data.filter(t=>t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting to errors. 1) Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object', 2) t.nameexOf is not a function

Comment: data is an array or Object?

Comment: data is an array of objects

Comment: it should not throw the error then, chekc and let me know

Comment: still getting the error: 
[app-scripts] [06:33:23]  typescript: src/providers/dummy-api/dummy-api.ts, line: 14
[app-scripts]             Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.
[app-scripts]       L13:  this.http.get('assets/data/companies.json').map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
[app-scripts]       L14:    this.companies = data.filter(t=>t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1);
[app-scripts]       L15:  });

Answer (score 0):

The filtered companies are now contained within the 'this.comapnies', if you want to use the companies in the component that has the 'companies' member, no need to return it from your filterCompanies function

Answer (score -1):

The filter does not modify the variable it works on, so you must assign it back to desire variable

```
filterCompanies(searchTerm) {
    this.http.get('assets/data/companies.json').map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
      this.companies = data.filter((company) => {
        return company.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: is not the same answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use includes to check if name contains search string

```
this.companies = [];

this.companies = data.filter((company) => company.name.includes('searchtext'));
```

or

```
this.companies = data.filter((company) => company.name.toLowerCase().includes('searchtext'.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: workaround? not sure. I believe Angular app itself will not work in IE without polyfills